# How can we handle multiple particle collisions at the same point?

Tags: simulation, game-engine, physics, collision, particles

I am asked to design a N-Body simulation system. Generally speaking, I need to write a program to handle the movement of multiple points under gravity in 3D space. I have no problem to detect the collision. However, it is possible that many points collide together at the same point. I have no idea how to calculate the velocity after the collision. What algorithm should I use for this situation?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423466/how-to-handle-multiple-simultaneous-elastic-collisions) SO question.

Answer (score 0):

This type of simulations are often addressed with a technique called [event-driven molecular dynamics](https://compphys.go.ro/event-driven-molecular-dynamics/), and multiple collisions are [ignored](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/61event/) if one is dealing with point-like particles (that is, objects without a "size", which are thus identified only by their position), for which the probability of having many-body collisions is exceedingly small.